# URL fails django validation, cannot ping, definitely exists

Tags: django, django-models, url-validation

I am trying to add this URL to a URLField in a model with URL validation: http://www.scscourt.org. Obviously the URL exists, but for whatever reason django won't validate it -- and I can't ping it either, but that could be a separate issue. Ideas?

Edit: Additionally, I have logged into the server and tried nslookup from there -- it finds the DNS info, and a wget returns the index page -- so my server can see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behind the scenes DJango sends a HEAD request to http://www.scscourt.org/.  When you do this ( I did it with [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)) they are actually denying you and sending back a 403.

You could technically set `verify_exists=False` for that particular link.

Comment: It's a generic model field -- there's got to be a way around this.

Comment: I am digging into the code now, the only way I think you are going to be able to do it, is if you change the django code.  You willing to do that?

Comment: @Briand D Do me a favor, and run your test with verify_exists=False and see if it works.  Because I just did a test here, and the verify_exist code is passing fine for your site.

Comment: That works fine. Switching it back to =True gives me the error again.